# zoom and scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

When I zoom the view,the scrolling doesn't work. 
How to fix this?Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSInteger count = 10;
NSInteger w = self.view.bounds.size.width;
NSInteger h = self.view.bounds.size.height;

UIScrollView* zoomCanvas;
UIScrollView* scrollCanvas;

zoomCanvas = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)];
[zoomCanvas setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
[zoomCanvas setMaximumZoomScale:2.0];
[zoomCanvas setDelegate:self];

scrollCanvas = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)];
[scrollCanvas setContentSize:CGSizeMake(w, h*count)];

srand(time(NULL));
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, h*i, w, h)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rand() % 255 / 255.0 green:rand() % 255 / 255.0 blue:rand() % 255 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [scrollCanvas addSubview:view];
}

[zoomCanvas addSubview:scrollCanvas];
[self.view addSubview:zoomCanvas];
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return [[scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

When I zoom the view,the scrolling doesn't work. 
How to fix this?Thanks.

Comment: The scrolling doesn't occur in the zoom canvas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about scrolling in the zoom canvas, it's probably because you did not set its content size.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
[super viewDidLoad]; 
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 

NSInteger count = 10; 
NSInteger w = self.view.bounds.size.width; 
NSInteger h = self.view.bounds.size.height; 

zoomCanvas = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)]; 
[zoomCanvas setMinimumZoomScale:1.0]; 
[zoomCanvas setMaximumZoomScale:2.0]; 
[zoomCanvas setDelegate:self]; 
[zoomCanvas setContentSize:CGSizeMake(w, h*count)]; 

dummyCanvas = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , w, h*count)]; 

srand(time(NULL)); 
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) { 
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, h*i, w, h)]; 
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rand() % 255 / 255.0 green:rand() % 255 / 255.0 blue:rand() % 255 / 255.0 alpha:1.0]; 
    [dummyCanvas addSubview:view]; 
} 

[zoomCanvas addSubview:dummyCanvas]; 
[self.view addSubview:zoomCanvas]; 
} 

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{ 
return dummyCanvas; 
}
```